# How to work with variables from a loop in HTML and with a component property?

Tags: javascript, angular

The data I work with (bosses[]) has a boss object with contains the key-value email which is an string. I want to create the anchor with that string in the HTML. Also note that there's a loop in HTML that allows to  access to each boss in bosses[].

So how can I access to create an anchor with boss.email which it only exists in the HTML loop?

I've tried `` <a [href]=`"mailto: + boss.email"></a> `` but doesn't work.

the html:

```html
<div  class="boss" *ngFor="let boss of bosses" >
    <div class="boss-text">
        <div class="boss-text-name">{{boss.name}} </div>
        <div>{{boss.email}}</div>
        <a [href]="mailto: + boss.email"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The component:

```js
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { boss} from 'interfaces'
        
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'boss-cell.component.html',
  selector: 'boss-cell',
})
export class BossCellComponent implements  OnInit {
  constructor() {}
    
  bosses: any[] =  [{
    email:       'kennedy@gmail.com',
    name:        'kennedy',
  }]
}
```

Comment: You can use string interpolation. like this <a [href]="mailto:" + boss.email></a>

Comment: String interpolation example - <a [href]=\`mailto: ${boss.email}\`></a>'

Answer (score 3):

You're close! I think this is what you're looking for:

```html
<div class="boss" *ngFor="let boss of bosses" >
    <div class="boss-text">
        <div class="boss-text-name">{{boss.name}} </div>
        <a [href]="'mailto:' + boss.email">{{ boss.email }}</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use interpolation as Suraj already mentionned in the comments, or bind to a function creating the string. Depending on weather you are going to link other elements to the mail, you should pick the cleanest option for you.

Template

```html
<div class="boss" *ngFor="let boss of bosses; let i = index">
  <div class="boss-text">
    <div class="boss-text-name">{{ boss.name }}</div>
    <a [href]="getMail(i)">{{ boss.email }}</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Script

```js
bosses: any[] =  [{
  email:       'kennedy@gmail.com',
  name:        'kennedy',
}]

getMail(index: number) {
  return 'mailto:' +  this.bosses[index].email
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to update this line

```
<a [href]="'mailto:' + boss.email">{{ boss.email }}</a>
```